# What's the best way to count clicks? and play sound according to corresponding click counts

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have an ImageView named Gun, if I click on it, it'll play Drawable Animation named gunShot.

so I declared an int

```
int gunCount = 0;
```

The first time you click Gun, it'll play soundReload and set the gunCount to 1, so it'll never play soundReload anymore.

Then click on it once, it'll play soundA, click on it twice, it'll play soundB, three times, soundC.

So every time I click on it, it'll start a Thread called gunThread, this Thread will check how many clicks and count it, and it'll play the sound according to how much click, after that it'll reset the int gunCount back to 0, and start the count again.

Here is my code:

First I declared my thread

```
final Thread Slash = new Thread(){
    public void run(){

        try{
            sleep(2000);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            if (gunCount == 3){
                gunShot.start();
                soundA.start();
                gunCount = 1;
            } else if (gunCount == 4){
                gunShot.start();
                soundB.start();
                gunCount = 1;
            } else if (gunCount == 5){
                gunShot.start();
                soundC.start();
                gunCount = 1;
            }       
        }

    }       
};
```

Then this is the onClick

```
Gun.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(gunThread.isAlive()){
                gunThread.stop();
            }

            if(gunShot.isRunning()){
                gunShot.stop();
            }

            if(gunCount == 0){
                gunShot.start();
                soundReload.start();
                gunCount = 1;

            } 

            else if(gunCount >= 1){
                sengokuState += 1;
                gunShot.start();
                gunThread.start();
            }

        }
    });
```

The point is, if you click on it twice simulatenously it would play soundB
click it three times, it would play soundC
click it once, soundA would play

the first click would be soundReload

I set a thread so it would wait the user input for how many gunCount in the sleep(2000).

Are there any better way to do this? Please tell me, this doesn't seem to work well.
Thanks.

Here is the edit:
    I insert this    final Thread playSound = new Thread(new Runnable() {

```
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //play the sound here with respect to clickCount
            if(clickCount == 2){
                soundA.start();
                clickCount = 2;
            }
            else if (clickCount == 3){
                soundB.start();
                clickCount = 2;
            }
            else if (clickCount == 4){
                soundC.start();
                clickCount = 2;
            }
        }
    });
```

the clickCount == 3 and clickCount == 4 doesn't work, any clues, anyway thanks.

Comment: make your variable static and global it will solved your problem `static int gunCount;`

Comment: how do I do that? Why?

Answer (score 0):

Well having a delay at the start seems a good way to do it. If it wasn't, I would not have problems with passing to the next song with my EarPods :)

Edit:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
    Thread playSound = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            //play the sound here with respect to clickCount

        }
    });
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            handler.removeCallbacks(playSound);
            handler.postDelayed(playSound, 2000);
            clickCount++;
        }
    });
```

Comment: By the way, it occurs to my mind now, you can use Handler for this case. Everytime you click, you can postDelay the playing sound task like in 2000ms and every time you click again, you remove the callback and postDelay it again. This way you can count the clicks as many times as you wan't and you play it after the last 2 second delay.

Comment: Did you change your code with the handler? If you did, try logging your code in onClick method and print out the clickCount so that you can see how much clickCount you have, you might probably miss the delay and it is playing the sound when clickCount is two? By the way, you need to set clickCount to 0 when you play the sound.

Answer (score 0):

you should consider something else rather than threads try this code

```
private void CountDown() {

    CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(3000,1000) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {


        }
    }.start();

}
```